# Powershell issue reading groups from txt file

Tags: windows, powershell

So, with the same code from my last question I've got a new problem. It returns a count, but there's two AD groups causing problems. We'll call them 'East Group' and 'West Group'. Both written exactly that way with spaces and thus requiring quotes. When I run:

```
(Get-ADGroup "East Group" -Properties *).member.count
```

It returns the count of users no problem. However, when I run the code for my grand total ignoring duplicates:

```
$script:cnt = 0
$Groups = Get-Content -Path $someFile
$Groups | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object -expand DistinguishedName -Unique | ForEach-Object { $script:cnt++ }
$script:cnt
```

It returns a total, but also an error saying that it cannot find West Group or East Group under my domain. My best guess is it's somehow ignoring the quotation marks in the text file. Is there a way to make it read it as "East Group" or some other workaround?

Comment: have you looked at what is in `$Groups`? you may need to wrap the [horribly foolishly named] groups with quotes before you use them.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I put the text file for `$Groups` together myself and was sure to put both East Group and West Group in quotes. These are the only two problem groups. Each group name is a single line. Are you saying put the entire list in quotes or each name? Should I have just typed it as a long line instead of hitting enter?

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps#required-parameters) say `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet requires any of these for its `Identity` parameter: `distinguishedName`, `objectGUID`, `objectSid`, `sAMAccountName`.  While 'East Group' and 'West Group' may very well be the Display names of these groups, check the properties in ADUC to find their SamAccount names and use those.

Comment: have you tried sending just the one problem item thru the pipeline? find the index in the `$Gruoups` collection and send that to see if it is the problem ... then add a `Write-Host` in there to see what is actually being passed along. ///// as for wrapping things - i was referring to  looking into explicitly wrapping each in quotes as it is fed to the cmdlets. pipe the collection to a `ForEach-Object` and use that to feed the cmdlet a quote-wrapped string. ///// i cannot test any of this since i have no AD access. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's somehow ignoring the quotation marks in the text file.

**Don't put quotation marks in your plain-text file with group names, if you're reading it with `Get-Content`** - such quotes will become *part of the values*, which is not your intent - simply rely on `Get-Content` to read the file *line by line*, which will work correctly even with values with spaces.

```
# Create the group-list file - do NOT use quotation marks around the entries.
@'
NoSpacesGroup
East Group
'@ > Groups.txt

# Demonstrate that each group name is read correctly, even if it
# contains spaces.
Get-Content Groups.txt | ForEach-Object { "this group: >>$_<<" }
```

The above yields:

```
this group: >>NoSpacesGroup<<
this group: >>East Group<<
```

demonstrating that even the value with spaces was correctly read as a single value (line).

Therefore, simply **remove the quotes from your group file and try your command again**.